# What would be the effect of a world with much less water?

Tags: climate, alternate-worlds, water, deserts

Say a world has, instead of about 70% water (earth), only 25% water. This would be in the form of one ocean, and all the rivers and lakes. The land has about five mountain ranges, and the planet is the size of Earth. Would it still be habitable, or just one big desert? Would it have an impact on the soil, making it less fertile?

Comment: Please see the sandbox in the meta: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions for help. There you can ask questions and whoever feels like it will comment on how to make the question better. The question lacks A LOT of information, I think the best idea would be to have it examined in the sandbox first.

Answer (score 0):

Tatooine. Anyway, its habitability would depend very much on the people living there and their capabilities. If they cause release of water vapour, it may actually help the planet. On the flip side, water pollution would exhaust the planet's resources WAY faster. So you can rule out heavy industry on such a planet.
This would more likely be a simple trading outpost or a mercenary hideout. Farming may be possible with proper irrigation and a ban on chemical fertilizers.  Moisture farming may be practised, if possible.
If the planet is sandy, some terraforming may be necessary to allow cultivation, by adding loam, clay and humus to the soil.
All in all, it could possibly be habitable, but would not provide a very happy existence.

Comment: So, it probably wouldn't create life on its own, but you could live there in a sci fi setting? Interesting... Also, I forgot about tatooine.

Comment: Well, if life develops, it certainly won't be  like our life, and will only develop in certain pockets. On the seashore, maybe. Given enough time, the indigenous life COULD adapt and move in towards the sandy, hot, dry mainland. Depends on how you want it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

### That depends

. . . on the location of the ocean and the distribution of the landmasses. Also, the amount of solar energy the planet receives and its atmospheric mix of N, O, CO2, etc. See [this article](https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/nitrogen-sources-and-cycling-in-the-ecosystem-and-its-role-in-air-waterand-soil-pollution-a-critical-review-2375-4397-1000136.php?aid=46511) for further info.

My point is that without defining further the planet's relative location to its primary star (or stars), a possible ecosystem on the ocean's surface affecting moisture re-uptake, the salinity of the ocean, the depth of the ocean, and the topography of the continent, it's too difficult to state whether or not the planet is habitable.

Certainly some rainfall will occur in some areas. If there is life evolving on the planet, some areas will be habitable. Although, in general, large continents away from large water sources *tend* to contain interiors that are drier than the surrounding land. The mountains and their elevation will create rain shadows, too.

Comment: Also, I suggest you update your question to be a bit more specific. Thanks! - DDM

Answer (score 0):

Water is the ultimate phase-change temperature-regulating material. So temperatures would be more extreme. And with extreme temperatures, weather would be more extreme as well.